# Get network stream and forward it

Tags: linux, ssh, vlc-media-player, streaming, raspberry-pi

I have a small problem with streaming from Raspberry Pi.
I'm using raspberry Pi Camera and streaming output from it this way:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -w 640 -h 480 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8554}' :demux=h264
```

I have public access to port 8554 and nothing else from my provider. The problem is, that I want to view the stream also on firewall secured networks (for example from my office, public networks, etc.), where a lot of ports are disabled. I have small VPS with public IP address.
So, is there any way how to get output (on my VPS) from raspberry:8554 and pass it to port 80? I tried something like:

```
cvlc -vvv http://raspberry:8554 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:80}' :demux=h264
```

but the video is grey or green and I can't recognize even shapes.
Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You tagged the post "port forwarding" but did not specify if the rasPi is behind NAT and you can forward all traffic to another port through your router's interface

Comment: Sorry about that. RasPI is behind NAT and I don't have any access to the router, but the internet provider (who controls the router) forwarded port 8554 to my raspberry.

Comment: I had a similar issue with an Argentinian ISP. I solved it by asking them to switch off NAT and installed my own router to the un-NATted connecction.

Answer (score 0):

The best Idea that comes to mind is installing zoneminder on your VPS.
Zoneminder will administer the stream from your cam and serve it in a web interface.

You also get the motion detection, alarms and video storage functionalities of Zoneminder.

This is way more than you asked, but my reasoning is that if you need to check your cam wherever you are you should do it with professional grade software.